# How to set selected item in dropdownlist using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Currently my code is selecting the first item in the list. I want it to select the item which matches the `MakeModelTypeCode`.

E.G.
The selected item in the dropdownlist should be where this code

```
 vehicleViewModel.VehicleDTO.VehicleDetails.MakeModelTypeCode
```

= `MakeModelTypeCode` from `x`

Here is the relevant code from the Business Logic class:

```
        vehicleViewModel.AvailableMakeModels = GetAllMakeModelTypesForClient(selectedClientId);

        vehicleViewModel.AvailableMakeModels = vehicleViewModel.AvailableMakeModels.GroupBy(x => x.ModelDescription).Select(x => x.First()).Distinct().ToList();

        var vehicleMakeList = vehicleViewModel.AvailableMakeModels
            .Select(s =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Selected = true,
                    Text = s.MakeDescription,
                    Value = s.MakeModelTypeCode
                });
```

Here is the relevant code from the .cshtml:

```
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VehicleDTO.VehicleDetails.MakeDescription)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedvendorText, new SelectList(Model.AvailableMakesSelectList, "Value", "Text", "Make"), new { @class = "form-control uppercase", @id = "ddlAvailableMakes", name = "ddlAvailableMakes", @onchange = "FillModels()" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedMake, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

Here is the code from the Controller:

```
    [Route("Edit-{id}")]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        VehicleViewModel vehicleViewModel = new VehicleViewModel();
        selectedClientId = HelperMethods.GetClientId();

        vehicleViewModel.VehicleDTO = this.vehicleBusinessLogic.GetClientVehicleDTO(id, this.selectedClientId);

        vehicleViewModel = this.vehicleBusinessLogic.SetUpUpdateVehicle(vehicleViewModel, selectedClientId);
        vehicleViewModel.VehicleDTO.VehicleDetails.ClientID = this.selectedClientId;

        return View(vehicleViewModel);
    }
```

I have tried a few different ways but can't get any to work. I can get just the item I want returned but not all the items + the selected item.

I was thinking I could do a nested Where clause inside the Select but that doesn't seem to work, but maybe my syntax was in-correct.

Comment: Your dropdownlist is for `SelectedvendorText` - its that value which determines what is selected. Set it to match one of your option values and it will be selected

Comment: And you view code makes no sense - you have a `LabelFor()` for one property, a `DropDownListFor()` for another property and a `ValidationMessageFor()` for yet another property.

Comment: Both of your comments combined to fix the issue. This is legacy code I've taken over. I was focusing solely on the Business Logic code but I should have looked at the cshtml first. Thank you. You can combine your comments as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Its a bit hard to add an answer when its really not clear exactly what you wanting to bind to - how is a property named `SelectedvendorText` related to `AvailableMakeModels`? And all this code (things like `vehicleViewModel.VehicleDTO.VehicleDetails.MakeModelTypeCode` suggests you using data models in your view which is not good practice

Comment: I changed the cshtml to this (which is your comments combined):
                                              `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.VehicleDTO.VehicleDetails.MakeDescription)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VehicleDTO.VehicleDetails.MakeModelTypeCode, new SelectList(Model.AvailableMakesSelectList, "Value", "Text", "Make"), new { @class = "form-control uppercase", @id = "ddlAvailableMakes", name = "ddlAvailableMakes", @onchange = "FillModels()" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedMake, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`

Comment: I also removed this line for the Business Logic as it's not needed  
`vehicleViewModel.AvailableMakeModels = vehicleViewModel.AvailableMakeModels.GroupBy(x => x.ModelDescription).Select(x => x.First()).Where(x => x.ClientID == selectedClientId).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139953/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-rmadd).

Comment: Can you try `@Html.DropDownList("PropertyName",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Items, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the .cshtml to the below resolved the issue.

The only change was to replace `x => x.SelectedvendorText` with `m => m.VehicleDTO.VehicleDetails.MakeModelTypeCode`

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VehicleDTO.VehicleDetails.MakeDescription)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VehicleDTO.VehicleDetails.MakeModelTypeCode, new SelectList(Model.AvailableMakesSelectList, "Value", "Text", "Make"), new { @class = "form-control uppercase", @id = "ddlAvailableMakes", name = "ddlAvailableMakes", @onchange = "FillModels()" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedMake, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
MakeModelTypeCode toBeSelected;

var vehicleMakeList = vehicleViewModel.AvailableMakeModels
            .Select(s =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Selected = s.MakeModelTypeCode == toBeSelected,
                    Text = s.MakeDescription,
                    Value = s.MakeModelTypeCode
                });
```

Comment: The `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored when binding to a model property using `DropDownListFor()` - its the value of the property which determines what is selected